# USB Mouse keeps cutting off/on on Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mouse, peripherals

I have a USB mouse that just recently has started turning off for a few seconds than switching back on. The light switches off and the cursor stops moving. Then it come back on. I have updated my drivers and swapped usb ports and still a problem.

I don't have any other mice to try, so before I go and buy another, any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always a possibility that the mouse is broken - random shutdowns are bad, and if its transient it could indicate bad caps, or a short somewhere or...

On the other hand i've had a mouse do that right until it stopped working, and it turned out it was a loose connector. Open it up, check that everything is nice and tight, plug and pray.

Considering you've tried switching USB ports, and back USB ports are in any case, less troublesome than front ones, and mice are dead cheap, getting a replacement wouldn't be a bad idea in any case.

Comment: +1 for 'plug and pray', not heard that for ages :)

Comment: I've had quite a few situations where opening up a bit of kit, and putting it back together magically fixes things.

Comment: I've done it a number of times with different things, laptops in the majority! Dead->dissemble->NFF->reassemble->working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you swap USB port to another one in the same location? i.e. did you swap from one back panel port to another on the back panel?

Try swapping to one in the front panel to rule out a problem on that part of the motherboard.

Comment: tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you another computer or laptop to test it on?